# Swi-Prolog gives error on Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I downloaded prolog on this website http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable version 7.4.2 for Yosemite 10.10.5, after that when opening .pl extension files, swi-prolog freezes. In addition, I downloaded development version 7.5.5 and nothing was change. I couldn't find any answer about this case. What can i do for this situation ?

Comment: Impossible to know what exactly you did or what happens by just reading your question :-(

Comment: You can always try to install from sources using either Homebrew or MacPorts.

Comment: It's hard to say, but since it's not a programming question, you might also get better feedback by writing to the [SWI Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swi-prolog) or to Jan Wielemaker directly.

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem by installing latest version of SWI-Prolog.